# Dynamically add columns in table - ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am doing a project for my faculty and I want to create a table where I can add columns dynamically.

One row can have a maximum of 4 columns and then it creates new row and it keeps inserting new columns and rows until the end. I have a table `Product` in SQL Server from which I want to populate this table.

Here is the code example for my table:

```
<table class="table border-0">
                        
<tr>
<td>                                
<div class="product">
<div class="product_image" style="width:300px;height:300px;"><img src="images/product_1.jpg" alt=""></div><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
                                    
<div class="product_content clearfix" style="width:300px;height:300px;">
                                        
<div class="product_info">
                                            
<div class="product_name"><a href="product.html">Woman's Long Dress</a></div>
                                            
<div class="product_price">$45.00</div>
                                        
</div>
                                        
<div class="product_options">
                                            
<div class="product_buy product_option"><img src="images/shopping-bag-white.svg" alt=""></div>
                                            
<div class="product_fav product_option">+</div>
                                        
</div>
                                    
</div>
                                
</div>
                            
</td>
                            
<td>
                                
<div class="product">
                                    
<div class="product_image" style="width:300px;height:300px;"><img src="images/product_1.jpg" alt=""></div><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
                                    
<div class="product_content clearfix" style="width:300px;height:300px;">
                                        
<div class="product_info">
                                            
<div class="product_name"><a href="product.html">Woman's Long Dress</a></div>
                                            
<div class="product_price">$45.00</div>
                                        
</div>
                                        
<div class="product_options">
                                            
<div class="product_buy product_option"><img src="images/shopping-bag-white.svg" alt=""></div>
                                            
<div class="product_fav product_option">+</div>
                                        
</div>
                                    
</div>
                                
</div>
                            
</td>                           
<td>
                                
<div class="product">
                                    
<div class="product_image" style="width:300px;height:300px;"><img src="images/product_1.jpg" alt=""></div><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
                                    
<div class="product_content clearfix" style="width:300px;height:300px;">
                                        
<div class="product_info">
                                            
<div class="product_name"><a href="product.html">Woman's Long Dress</a></div>
                                            
<div class="product_price">$45.00</div>
                                        
</div>
                                        
<div class="product_options">
                                            
<div class="product_buy product_option"><img src="images/shopping-bag-white.svg" alt=""></div>
                                            
<div class="product_fav product_option">+</div>
                                        
</div>
                                    
</div>
                                
</div>
                            
</td>

                            
<td>
                                
<div class="product">
                                    
<div class="product_image" style="width:300px;height:300px;"><img src="images/product_1.jpg" alt=""></div><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
                                    
<div class="product_content clearfix" style="width:300px;height:300px;">
                                        
<div class="product_info">
                                            
<div class="product_name"><a href="product.html">Woman's Long Dress</a></div>
                                            
<div class="product_price">$45.00</div>
                                        
</div>
                                        
<div class="product_options">
                                            
<div class="product_buy product_option"><img src="images/shopping-bag-white.svg" alt=""></div>
                                            
<div class="product_fav product_option">+</div>
                                        
</div>
                                    
</div>
                                
</div>
                            
</td>
                        
</tr>
```

Here is the `Product` model class:

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Author { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Range(1, 10000)]
    public double Price { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ValidateNever]
    public string ImageURL { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }

    [ValidateNever]
    public Category c { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int CoverTypeID { get; set; }

    [ValidateNever]
    public CoverType ct { get; set; }
}
```

My focus is on HTML part.

Comment: ...you haven't posted anything except HTML. Wheres's your C# and SQL code?

Comment: Im sorry I thought I added C# code. I will edit my post now.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you must use **jquery** for it like this.

This operation works in client

1. use `jQuery()` to your code run after page load
2. select element that you want duplicated
3. use `clone(true)` method to duplicated and insert it in variable
4. for end use `append()` method to duplicated

```js
jQuery(function(){
  /*Select element that want click to duplicated*/
  $(".duplicated").on("click", function(){
     var td = $(this).clone(true); /*Copy element that you want duplicated*/ 
     $("tr").append(td); /*Duplicate your element*/
  });
});
```

```css
td{
border: solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
<td class="duplicated">
<b>
click to duplicate
</b>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

This script just example. you must customize it selections **$()** to work correctly in your project.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: _"you must use jquery for it like this."_ - sorry but no: jQuery is not necessary for _anything_, and if anything, we need to stop using jQuery because now it's just a redundant dependency.